# Nothing happens when running python script from cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I recently made a program in Python that I need to launch from the command line.
However, when I run it with "python my_script.py", nothing happens, as if the program was ran but it was empty. Here is an illustration [image]

The 'test.py' file is a basic Hello World program. I started it in my editor , and it worked just fine.
I added python in my PATH as follows :
[image]

Python version is 3.7.6, I'm running W10x64 updated.
Does anyone know what the problem is ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you share the script code?

Comment: Try "py test.py". [What is the difference between 'py' and 'python' in the terminal?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50896577)

Comment: Does typing `python` start python?

Comment: Thanks for your help !
The script code is simply print("Hello World !").
Writing "py test.py" shows me that py isn't recognized as a system command

Comment: Typing python brings me to the Windows Store page of Python 3.8
I installed it via Anaconda, so I don't need to install it via Windows.
Can it be the issue ?

Comment: You're using Conda? Did you activate the environment?

Answer (score 3):

just had this issue and the solution was very simple. I had just installed vscode and I forgot I didn't have auto-save enabled. If anyone runs into this issue make sure you save your file before running it

Answer (score 2):

From the [Microsoft Dev Blog adding Python to the App store](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/#comment-36) - in order to remove the windows store trigger, [you need to change the app execution alias](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-app-execution-aliases-windows-10) by going to Settings, Apps & Features, Manage App Execution Aliases. There you can disable the Microsoft Store alias for Python.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Python with the Windows Store, that solved my problem.
As I had already Python installed outside the windows Store, it would be great to find a solution to use the installed python instead of the Store python when using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen because I was developing using Anaconda. That is, I did not have a straight copy of python installed on my machine. Instead, I needed to start up the appropriate Anaconda environment in the command line and then run the program from there.

```
(env) C:\Users\UserName>python filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with recent versions of windows the file association is used to determine which program  to be used. So exclude "python" and it should work.

```
(env) C:\Users\UserName>filename.py
```

reference:
https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/